# Uncaught (in promise) : NotSupportedError: GATT Error Unknown

Tags: bluetooth-gatt, web-bluetooth

I am trying to write data which is 490 in length to a device using Web Bluetooth API. When I try to write I get NotSupportedError: GATT Error Unknown.

I am using chrome browser on android.

My app is in Angular 7 and I am using @types/web-bluetooth.

Below is the code:

```
navigator.bluetooth
.requestDevice({
filters: [{ name: this.deviceName }],
optionalServices: [this.GATT_SERVICE],
})
.then((device) => {
return device.gatt.connect();
})
.then((server) => {
return server.getPrimaryService(this.GATT_SERVICE);
})
.then((service) => {
this.gattService = service;
return this.gattService.getCharacteristic(this.GATT_CHAR);
})
.then((characteristic) => {
    characteristic.writeValueWithResponse(this.arraybufferdata);
})
.catch(async (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Is the issue related to the length? Can you reproduce error with less bytes in `this.arraybufferdata`?

Nit: You may want to return promise so that error gets propagated.

```js
.then((characteristic) => {
    return characteristic.writeValueWithResponse(this.arraybufferdata);
})
```